# Output shows unessesary number in C

Tags: c, for-loop, output

I am writing a program to ask the user to enter a date and when the user enters 0/0/0 as the date the program stops asking the user to enter dates, but i have a problem with the output, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){

int d, m, y;



for (;d!=0 && m!=0 && y!= 0;){

printf("Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx): ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &d, &m, &y);

}

    return 0;
}
```

Once this program is ran the output is "Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx):" As long as 0/0/0 is not an input, The program is that the output looks like this:

```
Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx): 5/5/5
Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx): 6/6/6
6Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx): 7/7/7
7Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx): 4/4/4
7Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx): 3/3/3
7Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx):
```

As you can see the output the problem is that on each newline the largest number is shown on each new line regardless or whether it belongs to d, m or y variables. **Why is this and how do i fix this?**

Comment: your code never prints the output at all. are you showing us your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your loop accesses `d`, `m`, `y`, even though these have not received an initial value. That is undefined behavior.  Did you mean `int d = 1, m = 0, y = 0`?

As for the extra iteration, the program is just doing what you asked. While those variables are not zero, ask for more input.  You put in 3/3/3 and so the variables are not zero, so it asks for more input.

I set `d = 1` above so that the loop is entered the first time; if we initialize the variables all to zero, the loop won't execute.

We could work with uninitialized variables, if we switch from a top-of-loop test to bottom-of-loop

One of the ways to do a bottom-of-loop test in C is to use the `do`/`while` loop:

```
do {
   // ask for input
} while (d != 0 && m != 0 && y != 0); // unless zeros were given, ask again
```

One problem with `do` is that the terminating expression doesn't have any inner variables in scope, so for instance this idiom is not possible:

```
do {
   int x = some_function();
   // ...
} while (x != 0); // x is not in scope here!
```

This is probably one reason why the `do` loop doesn't get used as much as `for` and `while`. In that kind of situation we can make an infinite loop with `for (;;)` and then stick in the bottom-of-loop test as an `if` with a break:

```
for (;;) {
   int x = some_function();
   // ...
   if (x == 0)  // note inversion: while (x != 0) -> if (x == 0)
      break;
   // nothing else here, hence "bottom-of-loop test"
}
```

Lastly, I would discourage you from using `scanf` for interactive input. If the user makes any kind of mistake in the input syntax, `scanf` provides no error recovery. `scanf` is all right for processing data files which are in specific program and expected to be correct. When using `scanf`, you should capture its return value and act on it: it indicates how many conversions were successfully made, and may return the negative value `EOF` if no conversions were made.

To obtain interactive input in a way that is a bit more robust, we can use `fgets` to read lines from the user, using a generous buffer size. Then, scan the contents of the buffer using the string version of `scanf`, namely `sscanf` (also intercepting `sscanf`'s return value and acting on it to provide error diagnosis and recovery).

Note also that if we call `scanf("%m", &m)` but no successful conversion takes place (such that `scanf` returns 0 or `EOF`), then in that case `m` retains its previous value. If `m` is uninitialized, then it stays uninitialized. If you don't check the result of `scanf`, your program will work with old values, thinking they are new.

> *As you can see the output*

I can see the output, but nothing in the program which produces the output. Hopefully these hints will help.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code it terminates immediately, probably because by chance the values of `d`, `m`, and `y` happen to be zero when the program starts. When I change the program to use a specific flag to indicate the first pass through the loop (and I changed to loop to a `while` loop, as that's what's really going on) I don't get your reported problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
  {
  int d, m, y, first = 1;

  while(first || (d!=0 && m!=0 && y!= 0))
    {
    first = 0;

    printf("Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &d, &m, &y);
    }

  return 0;
  }
```

The output of the above is:

```
Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx): 1/2/3                                                                                                                                                   
Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx): 4/5/6                                                                                                                                                   
Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx): 7/8/9                                                                                                                                                   
Enter a date (xx/xx/xxxx): 0/0/0
```

[Online GDB here](https://onlinegdb.com/BJGyJQaTU)

Comment: an example how to overcomplicate the code. why not simple: https://onlinegdb.com/Hk2V-mTTU